# how to Add Facebook SDK & Analytics to App using swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

how to Add Facebook SDK & Analytics to App using swift.

i try to implement FB analytic on iOS application (using swift).

Here my code. but i cannot track MY CUSTOME EVENT on Facebook Events Manager.

**PodFile**

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

**Info.plist**

```
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fb****</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FacebookAppID</key>
        <string>****</string>
        <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
            <string>****</string>
        <key>FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled</key>
            <true/>
        <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
            <string>****</string>
        <key>FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled</key>
            <true/>
        
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
            <array>
              <string>fbapi</string>
              <string>fbapi20130214</string>
              <string>fbapi20130410</string>
              <string>fbapi20130702</string>
              <string>fbapi20131010</string>
              <string>fbapi20131219</string>
              <string>fbapi20140410</string>
              <string>fbapi20140116</string>
              <string>fbapi20150313</string>
              <string>fbapi20150629</string>
              <string>fbapi20160328</string>
              <string>fbauth</string>
              <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
              <string>fbauth2</string>
              <string>fbshareextension</string>
            </array>
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled =  true
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        AppEvents.activateApp()
  
    }
```

**Home_VC.swift**

```
import FBSDKCoreKit  
class Home_VC: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AppEvents.logEvent(AppEvents.Name(rawValue: "MY CUSTOME EVENT NAME"))
     }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsIRJ.png)

Comment: Have you filled all information in Info.plist correctly?

Comment: i don't know.  i add Facebook Configure inside info.plist. CFBundleURLSchemes, FacebookAppID, FacebookClientToken, FacebookDisplayName are correct. security purpose here this all information is hidden.